# Kivy Garden - Multiple Chromium Embedded Browsers, can only change the URL of first created one?

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, chromium-embedded

In my code I have a GridLayout with rows of Button - TextInput. I also have a dictionary with keys representing indices and values storing CefBrowsers. Whenever a button is pressed, the GridLayout is restructured so that the button is replaced by the associated CefBrowser. Or if one hasn't been made yet, then a new browser is constructed and added to the dictionary.

Every browser made is stored in this Dictionary (as deleting/removing the browsers from the Grid doesn't seem to prevent them from running in the background. Ex: Audio continues to play) so whenever a certain button is pressed, each currently existing browser is supposed to change its URL to a "blank site."

For some reason, though, any calls to change the URL of any CefBrowser only changes the URL of the first created browser. Any ideas why? Or how I can change this?

Relevant Code:

```
def replaceButton(self, instance):
    browserNumber = instance.getIndex()/2
    try:
        browser = self.activeBrowsers[browserNumber]
        browser.change_url(instance.getURL())
    except KeyError: #browser doesn't already exist
        self.activeBrowsers[browserNumber] = CefBrowser(start_url=instance.getURL(), size_hint_x=1,
                                                        size_hint_y=None)
        browser = self.activeBrowsers[browserNumber]
    self.feed.replace(instance.getIndex(), browser)

def restartFeed(self):
    self.feed.empty()
    for browser in self.activeBrowsers.values():
        print(browser)
        browser.change_url('http://blank.org/')
    self.readData()
```

I can imagine the replaceButton method not working because of a logical error, but I've checked the individual Browser objects in restartFeed, and although each one is unique, again, only the first one seems to change its URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: this was fixed in cefpython v31.

Unfortunately, this is a bug in CEFPython. You can only use one `Browser` instance because certain methods (such as `LoadUrl` and `ExecuteJavascript`) always affect the first `Browser` created. :(

https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/issues/detail?id=97

It looks like a fix has been found and is scheduled for the next release. You could try downloading and building CEFPython from source, applying the patch in that issue link if necessary.

A workaround for this is to create each `Browser` with the correct starting URL, then destroy and recreate the `Browser` to change the URL. But that's very inefficient.

Comment: Hmm, can you leave me a snippet of code to definitively remove a browser then? My previous attempts seem to have left the browser running in the background. For example, the audio continues to play from a link after removing the browser from the grid object and, I think, deleting the reference.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself (I only need one browser in my app), but you probably just need to call `browser.CloseBrowser(True)`. https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/wiki/Browser

Comment: Regrettably CloseBrowser() doesn't seem to be defined in the Kivy Garden Widget, but thanks though!

Comment: The CEFPython `Browser` instance is stored in the `browser `attribute. So call `<widget>.browser.CloseBrowser(True)`.